# Crystal report PDF showing differently

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

[image: Report Pdf]

See the picture, There is no columns in second page but it is showing header i want to remove that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you will need to make report body smaller in the report designer. Please try that and try to reduce your report margins. If this will not help, please post the picture of your report in the designer

Answer (score 0):

you can overcome from this issue by suppressing the footer section in the report.

Comment: footer does not create this output in crystal. look at provided image.

Comment: That i know.. can u chk by suppressing any blank footer..bcoz i  faced same issue.